# MacVim and Latex: How to quickly compile and preview?

Tags: vim, latex, macvim

The latex package provides MacVim with menu items to compile and preview.

I'd like to execute these functions via keypress, perhaps with `\ + something`

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

try automatic latex plugin - http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/
add to your `.vimrc`

```
set localleader = "\\"
```

then compilation is `\l` and you can view the result with `<f3>`, and read the documentation 
`:help atp`

Answer (score 0):

Light-weight alternative: [TeX-PDF](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3230).

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy using [LaTeX Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box) when writing LaTeX in vim. It includes many handy tools, like background compilation, a table of contents for navigation, and useful key-maps for autocompletion and navigation. I certainly think its worth the (short amount) of time to learn if you are going to be using vim for LaTeX.